# In pandas, can I simultaneously map and insert column to specific index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, insert

In pandas, is it possible to simultaneously map and insert a new column to a specific index/place in a dataframe?

I can get the mapping to work (from a multi key dictionary), successfully creating a new column at the end of my dataframe.

```
#using multi_key_dict https://pypi.python.org/pypi/multi_key_dict
from multi_key_dict import multi_key_dict
k = multi_key_dict()
k['AAAA', 'BBBB'] = 'San Francisco'
k['CCCC'] = 'Los Angeles'
k['DDDD', 'EEEE', 'FFFF',] = 'San Diego'

# Add new column 'location' to df, based on results of mapping dictionary K to existing column 'codes'
df['location'] = df['codes'].map(k.get)
```

I know I can (re)index and specify the sort order.

Additionally, I know I can insert columns at a specified index/position in a dataframe:

```
df.insert(index,name,value)
```

It would be nice/elegant if I could code the mapping and insert the column at a specified index together. Something like this conceptual guess:

```
df['location'] = df['codes'].map(k.get).insert(5,'location')
```

Comment: No. You need to insert and then reorder.

Answer (score 0):

I did the reorder/sort after the mapping and insert, using...

Original column order: `['col1', 'col2', 'col3']`

Reordered using: `df = df[['col3', 'col2', 'col1']]`

Answer (score 0):

```
df.insert(5,'location',df['codes'].map(k.get))
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of your answer.